# Using Pandas, can I create a new column that returns a binary variable based on whether a value exists across multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have a dataframe with 4 columns, 3 of which are binary true/false, and the first column being a unique identifier.

Is there any way, using pandas, that I can add an additional column to this dataframe that returns true or false based on whether a true (i.e. 1) value exists across more than 1 of the 3 binary columns? I am very new to learning CS, Python, and pandas so any answer would be insightful.

Thanks!

Comment: `df[[col1,col2,col3]].any(axis=1)`

Comment: @QuangHoang: he wants at least 2 cols having `True`, so `any` would not be enough. Perhaps, `df[[col1,col2,col3]].sum(axis=1).gt(1)`

Comment: @AndyL. That did the trick, thanks!

Comment: @VincentHa: glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this answers your "question" but it should work for your particular use case.

```
df['dups'] = df['col1'] + df['col2'] + df['col3'] > 1
```